# herhalten müssen

Tags: meaning-in-context

Aus vielen Quellen habe ich bisher nur widersprüchliche Bedeutungen von dieser Wendung gesehen, darum wende ich mich an die Seite. 
https://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/herhalten%20m%C3%BCssen%20%28f%C3%BCr%29
https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~f%C3%BCr%20etwas%20herhalten%20m%C3%BCssen&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou

Anscheinend gibt es mehrere Bedeutungen. Die passen jedoch meistens nicht in den Kontext. Z.B.

> Fahrer des Autos „Manta“ mussten für eine eigene Witz-Gattung herhalten.

Comment: Könntest du zusammenfassen, was du der als Link hier aufgeführten Internet-Fundstelle entnimmst und was Dir dabei konkret nicht klar ist?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Wenn ich "herhalten müssen" durch die synonymen Wendungen in diesem Satz, aber auch in anderen, ersetze, ergibt das keinen Sinn.

Comment: Ich wollte andeuten, dass es schöner wäre, du würdest die Frage vollständig formulieren (anstatt darauf zu setzen, dass Leser dem Link folgen und sich ihren eigenen Reim machen). Dieses Forum ist so angelegt, dass die Beiträge auch längerfristig aktuell und lesbar bleiben. Mit Links ist das immer so eine Sache...

Comment: Ich wollte damit zeigen, dass ich schon vorher recherchiert habe und trotzdem die Bedeutung nicht verstehe. Ansonsten finde ich, dass diese Link längerfristig verfügbar sein werden.

Comment: Was genau ist an dem (auch im Link erwähnten) Synonym "ertragen müssen" unverständlich?

Comment: @VollDerChecker: Kannst du den Link-Inhalt bitte knapp in der Frage zusammenfassen? Ich bin hier mobil und öffne nicht gerne Webseiten, die mir womöglich den Rest meiner Bandbreitenquota leersaugen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das Beispiel

> Die Fahrer des Autos „Manta“ mussten für eine eigene Witz-Gattung herhalten.

entspricht den abgeführten Definitionen dieser Redewendung. Da der Fahrer Opfer einer eigenen Witzgattung wurde, muss er, im übertragenen Sinne, wissentlich oder unwissentlich seinen 'Kopf hinhalten'.

Als Metapher: Die Erfindung der Witzgattung entspricht einem fallendem Schafottbeil, da es oft schmerzliche Konsequenzen mit sich bringt. Getroffen dadurch wird der Fahrer - er hält also seinen Kopf hin.

Answer (score 3):

Manchmal ist auch Onkel Duden hilfreich:

http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/herhalten

> herhalten
>
> 1) etwas in Richtung auf den Sprechenden halten, sodass er es erreichen kann
>
> 2) meist in Verbindung mit »müssen«; [anstelle eines anderen, von etwas anderem] zu, für, als etwas benutzt werden, dienen

Im Universalwörterbuch wird dann noch hinzugefügt:

> er muss für die anderen herhalten
>
> etwas muss als Vorwand herhalten
>
> er musste wieder [als Zielscheibe des Spottes] herhalten

Hier noch einige wohlgeformte Sätze mit "herhalten" (meist in der Bedeutung von *dienen für* oder *anstatt*)

> Das Tablet muss als PC-Ersatz herhalten
>
> Das Fahrrad muss als Lieferwagen[-Ersatz] herhalten
>
> Putin muss als Sündenbock herhalten
>
> Pillen müssen für Nahrungsmittel herhalten
>
> Socken müssen als Schuhe herhalten

Tja. Jetzt musste diese Website wieder als Wörterbuch-Ersatz herhalten...